# Data Binding Kotlin Android studio errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to use Data binding library in my project, that is written in Kotlin. I am using Kotlin v.1.0.2 & Gradle plugin v. 2.12 and with binding compiler. My build.gradle configured as follows:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
dependencies {
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2"
    provided "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.12"
}
```

In my Fragment layout I declared `<data>` block with some variables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="com.xxx.ui.AuthorizationPresenter"/>
        <import type="com.xxx.entity.AuthProvider"/>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.xxx.ui.authorization.Model"/>
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="com.xxx.ui.authorization.AuthorizationPresenter"/>

    </data>
    <FrameLayout
  ... />
</layout>
```

And then in my `AuthorizationFragment.kt` class I am setting these variables:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentAuthorizationBinding.inflate(inflater)
    binding?.presenter = presenter
    binding?.model = Model()
    binding?.addOnRebindCallback(object : OnRebindCallback<FragmentAuthorizationBinding>() {
        override fun onPreBind(binding: FragmentAuthorizationBinding?): Boolean {
            val sceneRoot = binding?.root as ViewGroup
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot)
            return true
        }
    })
    return binding?.root
}
```

And the problem is though this code successfully compiles and builds APK, Android studio marks these lines

```
binding?.presenter = presenter
binding?.model = Model()
```

as invalid and shows the following error: `Cannot access class 'com.xxx.ui.authorization.AuthorizationPresenter'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`. 
I tried to add `kapt 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'` to my `build.gradle`, but nothing has changed.
Also worth to mention that problem is only appears when I write my fragment in Kotlin, when it is written in Java everything is ok.

Comment: It's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12402

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Very useful tracker for those using Kotlin. 
Seems like something related to Kotlin Lint, I think

Answer (score 1):

Until the IDE shows the error, you can use this:

```
binding.setVariable(BR.model, Model())
```

It is not so concise as kotlin form but the red color will not drive you crazy any more ;)